# Why won't the lists be appended to my global list?

Tags: python, list, recursion, append

I wrote the following code, used to generate all possible combinations of a specific number of elements with help of recursion:

```
global_values = []
parameters = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
content = ["x","y","v","sd"]

def rec(values, depth):
    if(depth == 0):
        global_values.append(values)
        print values
        return

    for i in range(0,len(parameters)):
        values.append(parameters[i])
        rec(values,depth-1)
        values.pop()
    return

rec([],len(content))

print "!!!!----------!!!!"
print global_values
```

The "print "value"" statement prints the correct results, but I would like to append this results to the global list. Why doesn't this work?

With

```
parameters = [1,2,3]
content = ["x","y"]
```

I get the output:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
!!!!----------!!!!
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

But I want the last list filled with the values printed before.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `itertools.combinations()` ?

Comment: @mhlester You're right. I only glanced at the code and saw the OP was locally modifying a global without declaring it as such. I should have realized what was happening before I commented. Oops! =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time you append `values` to `global_values`, there are numbers in the list `values`. However, you remove those numbers later, and thus the list that was appended to `global_values` is now empty. This problem happens because there is only ever **one** list `values` that keeps getting re-used.

To see what I mean try:

```
list1 = []
list2 = [5,9]
list1.append(list2)
list2.pop() # Because list2 is inside list1, this changes the contents of list1
print list1 # Prints [[5]]
```

To append a **copy** of `values` use `global_values.append(values[:])`.